# Can anybody explain in a detail manner what this line of code does?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Idea.where("user_id = ?", id)
```

and also I wanted to ask, when should we pass param[:id]. I find it very confusing as to how where does rails find the parameters and how does this "params" work

Answer (score 2):

It fetches all the records from the `ideas` table that have in their `user_id` column the value of the variable `id`.

For example if `id` is `3` this would be equivalent to:

```
Idea.where(user_id: 3)
```

The `?` is a [placeholder and prevents against SQL injection attacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions).

Comment: Thanks but from where can I know this "current" value of variable id?

Comment: @redilhom It is a local variable so it depends on what value it has been assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Probably provides sql query like `select * from ideas where user_id = 14`. Where `14` is the value of `id` variable. But first returns scope object. Query will be executed when necessary.